# Uploading to google cloud bucket with angular2/4

Tags: node.js, angular, google-cloud-storage, bucket

How can i upload images / files to google cloud bucket using angular2/4. Is it a must i use Nodejs and express to get the task done. Please what is the best way to upload to gcs from angular2/4 project. Thanks  in advance.

Comment: Use firebase or cloudinary instead.